# How can I tell ApolloClient to refetch a specific query and rerender the component?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm a novice at using ApolloClient, so I'm sorry if this is a bad question, but I could really use some help. I'm used to using Redux and class based components, using Apollo with functional components and hooks is very new to me, I don't know how to do even the simplest things.

Right now I'm trying to implement an auth system. I have queries that send user credentials and receive the auth token. I have a header, which is a separate component from the signup/login form, which displays the Login or Logout button. It uses a query that sends the auth token to the protected route, and receives back user info (like username).

My task is very simple - once the "logout" button is clicked, I want the query that fetches the user information to be refetched, and the header component to be rerendered, so that instead of the "logout" button it displays the "login" button instead.

I'm doing it like this:

```
export default function Header() {
  const { data, refetch } = useQuery(USER_INFO)
  function logout() {
    cookieCutter.set("Authorization", "", { expires: new Date(0) })
    refetch()
  }
  return (
    <header>
      [...]
      // If there's user info inside of data, render logout button, otherwise render login button.
      <a onClick={logout}>
        Logout
      </a>
      [...]
    </header>
  )
}
```

So I'm trying to remove the auth cookie, and then refetch the query. I expect that running the `refetch()` function will refetch the query, which will return the empty `data` object (because there isn't any auth token anymore), and rerender the component to now display the "login" button.

But when I just click the "logout" button, the component does not rerender. If I refresh the page manually, it sees that there's no token, and renders the "logout" button as expected.

I feel like there must be a simple and standard approach to do something like this, but I don't know what that is. Can you help me out?

(I know about the `refetchQueries` parameter you can pass to mutations, but it doesn't apply here).

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

If you use Apollo you don't need Redux.

For the auth take a look at [this](https://medium.com/ovrsea/token-authentication-with-react-and-apollo-client-a-detailed-example-a3cc23760e9)